# _id property undefined within schema middleware

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am deleting a user and trying to cascade delete the user's posts, comments for each post, and replies for each deleted comment.

I keep getting "undefined" for the ._id properties within each schema's middleware so I cannot remove them from the database.

How do I access the id property to delete each comment for every post?

Thanks guys

USER MODEL MIDDLEWARE

```
userSchema.pre('remove', async function (next) {
  const user = this

  await Post.deleteMany({ userId: user._id }) // WORKS!

  next()
})
```

POST MODEL MIDDLEWARE - DOES NOT TRIGGER

```
postSchema.pre('deleteMany', async function (next) {
  const post = this

  await Comment.deleteMany({ postId: post._id }) // id = undefined

  next()
})
```

Comment: `await Post.remove({ userId: user._id })`.

Comment: I added your code and updated the code above but it will not trigger my postSchema middleware to delete all comments for each post. It will delete the posts though. Why won't it delete all of the comments?